# Search for file permisions other than 755

Tags: permissions, find, aix, recursive

In AIX really, how can I search in several directories and those below it, for files that are not of the specific permissions of 755.

So I want to search `/path/to/`, `/path/to/mydir`, `/path/to/mydir/andthisoneto`, etc., but not `/path`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want this:

```
find /path -mindepth 2 -type f -not -perm 0755
```

Or maybe just this, if my understanding is off:

```
find /path/to -type f -not -perm 0755
```

Comment: Yes, I want something like the second. One I plugged your commands in but got these errors:

find: 0652-017 -mindepth is not a valid option

find: 0652-017 -not is not a valid option.

Comment: Odd, what unix are you using? Also try: find -version

Comment: ok really it is AIX. find -version doesn't return a version.

Comment: AIX uses ! to negate instead of -not, so: find /path/to -type f ! -perm 0755

Comment: Yes, the find /path/to -type f ! -perm 0755 works. However is there a way to pipe this into ls -l so I can see the privs and owners - Thanks.

Comment: Just add the -ls option.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I found the best way was this:

```
  ls -l `find /path/to -type f ! -perm 0755`
```

Thanks for all those who helped me.

Comment: `# find /path/to -type f ! -perm 0755 -exec ls -l '{}' \;`

Comment: vj, I tried you way but had no luck, but solution above works great.